# Does redefining attributeGroup with itself have any effect?

Tags: xsd

XML schema of XHTML Basic 1.1 ([xhtml-basic11-modules-1.xsd file](http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/SCHEMA/xhtml-basic11-modules-1.xsd)) contains such a redefine:

```
<xs:redefine schemaLocation="http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/SCHEMA/xhtml-image-1.xsd">
    <xs:annotation>
        <xs:documentation>
    Image module

    Elements defined here:
      * img
        </xs:documentation>
        <xs:documentation source="http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml-modularization/abstract_modules.html#s_imagemodule"/>
    </xs:annotation>
    <xs:attributeGroup name="xhtml.img.attlist">
        <xs:attributeGroup ref="xhtml.img.attlist">
            <xs:annotation>
                <xs:documentation>
            Original Image Attributes (in Image Module)
         </xs:documentation>
            </xs:annotation>
        </xs:attributeGroup>
    </xs:attributeGroup>
</xs:redefine>
```

Is that any different from simply including the image module? It seams to me like it doesn't change anything, but I'm no XML Schema expert.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My initial answer was:

> Including the image module would have added everything that is defined there to the schema, whereas using `xsd:redefine` only the `attributeGroup xhtml.img.attlist` is imported.

but it is not the case - everything in the referenced schema is included, so the answer appear to be that there is no reason for that `xsd:redefine`.

Comment: Are you sure? As I read the spec, redefine is used to "incorporate components corresponding to a schema document _with modifications_". To me, that means the not-redefined types/groups/etc are incorporated as well. Also, that's what the example in the XML Schema primer implies.

Comment: You're right (and my answer is wrong) - do be sure I tested it and everything in the schema referenced by the `xs:redefine` is also in the referencing schema. I am fixing my answer.